# Fundamental Set of Solutions and Wronksian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Explain why the pair of functions $y_1(x) = x$ and $y_2(x) = \sin(x)$ cannot form a set of fundamental solutions to a second order homogeneous differential equiationon the interval $(-1,1)$.

Workings:

$W=\begin{bmatrix}x&\sin(x)\\1&\cos(x)\end{bmatrix}$

$W = x\cos(x) - \sin(x)$

If $x = 0$ then:

$W = 0\cos(0) - \sin(0)$

$W = 0$

I'm not sure if this was what i\I was supposed to do. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Wronskian is non-zero at some initial point, then it stays non-zero at all times. See the contradiction?

$x$ satisfies $y''=0$ and $\sin(x)$ satisfies $y''+y=0$, so the minimal combination having both as solutions is
$$
y^{(4)}+y''=0.
$$

Comment: Yeah, I do. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem:** Supposed $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ possess at least $n-1$ derivatives. If the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix} f_1 & f_2 & \cdots & f_n\\ f'_1 & f'_2 & \cdots & f'_n\\ . &. &. &.\\ . &. &. &.\\ f_1^{(n-1)}&f_2^{(n-1)} &\cdots  &f_n^{(n-1)} \end{vmatrix}$$ is not *zero* for **at least one point** in the interval *I*, then these functions are linearly independent on the interval.

Comment: Could you explain the connection to the question? Are the $f_k$ solutions of a linear ODE? Is linear independence meant as functions on the interval, then the statement is trivial, or pointwise for the the derivative vectors, then it is wrong. Also note that $x$ and $\sin x$ are linearly independent as functions.